# Using MongoDB objectID in query parameter, does it affect SEO?

Tags: seo, mongodb

If we use object id of MongoDB in query parameter like for example,

In browser URL,

```
http://example.com/get-details/507f191e810c19729de860ea
```

to pass this objectID from one state to another state, I am using `$stateparam`

then,in `$http` the URL will be

```
"/get_details?id="+$stateParams.detail_id

$http.get("/get_details?id="+$stateParams.detail_id).then(...);
```

Is there any problem with the URL in browser in terms of SEO,

i.e,  `http://example.com/get-details/507f191e810c19729de860ea`? If so then what could be the solution?

Comment: Let us know what server environment you're using so users can make suggestions. In the future, rather than [cross-posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331189/use-mongodb-objectid-in-query-parameter-does-it-affect-seo) to another Stack Exchange site, flag the question on the original site (on Stack Overflow) to request that it be migrated to the other site. That way answers aren't spread out over two sites. This is the right site to ask these types of questions on by the way.

Comment: I am using expressJS, MongoDB for Database, My client said the ObjectID  of MongoDB is not good for SEO, I do not know much about SEO, Can someone educate me on that, Can I use ObjectID like this one  '507f191e810c19729de860ea'

Comment: Sure, as pointed out on Stack Overflow, look up at the URL for this question, it has an ID string in it too, and you'll likely see it indexed in Google in a few minutes. The ID string in your URL is however pretty long, so some might chose to rewrite it so that visitors might relate to it better (i.e., to something they understand better). If you let us know what web server you're using (e.g., Node.js, Apache, etc...),  and a URL you'd like to rewrite to (e.g., `http://example.com/get-details/shoes`), users might suggest how to do that.

Comment: Thanks dan, One last question I have is instead of 'http://example.com/get-details/shoes' can i use this pattern of url (just like stackoverflow url), i.e, 'http://example.com/get-details/507f191e810c19729de860ea/shoes', Because I have to pass that id in URL Param, Thank you very much

Comment: Sure, as long as it's a valid URL (i.e., it doesn't contain special characters in it), you're fine. Adding an identifiable word like "shoes" to the URL might result in users being more willing to click on it. We have a lot of questions here on URL rewriting should you need help with that.

Comment: Thank you very Much, You saved My life, :)


in angular App we have like "http://example.com/#/home/details/507f191e810c19729de860ea/shoes", I know this will not work, If I do HTML5Mode Hack does it work ?

Comment: No problem, feel free to post other questions about webmastering here in the future.

Comment: Hi Dan, Sorry to trouble you again, some people say its correct and some say it is not, whom should I believe, can you please check this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331189/use-mongodb-objectid-in-query-parameter-does-it-affect-seo, Thanks

Comment: Looks like you edited your comment with another question after my last comment... I think you're confusing people by combining several questions into one (SEO, HTML5Mode, and security). For SEO, the URL you posted is not an issue, though it would look better to visitors to change it to a slug.  For using HTML5Mode, you'll need to ask specifically about that on Stack Overflow. Regarding security, you should probably ask that on [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/). Each SE site has its own focus and areas considered on-topic for them.

Comment: No Dan, since I am new stack overflow, I did not know about stack overflow has separate domains for each topic, well thanks for the answer, I will end here, thanks for the suggestion, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a great misconception that in order to have better SEO you must have a human readable URL written as a statement or as the page title. There is absolutely no issue with having a record ID number in the URL if that is the logical identifier for the content being displayed. There are many sites out there that use integers, and even GUID's in the URL to identify a file uniquely (in database driven systems). This is not an issue with SEO as SEO focuses on the value of the content. Yes the URL does play a part in the ranking but having a record ID number in the URL is not a huge issue against the value of the page content itself.